# Django Rest Framework POST method show api interface

Tags: django, post, django-rest-framework

I created a method on Django rest framework that only accepts POST (user registration), but what I want is that when I type that url. I want to have user interface that I can enter desired data. But instead I get en error 'function' object has no attribute 'get' (which totally make sense) but what how do I implement that default rest framework view that I can enter data (I am not that experienced with class based views)?

this is my code (rest framework view):

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = get_user_model().objects
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            self.permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

        return super(UserViewSet, self).get_permissions()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The queryset should be`User.objects.all()`.